# Pass js object with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I need to send a js object to the server through ajax request;
is an object containing parameters for a sql query with Sequelize orm in node js; an example is like this:

```
var data =
{
    include: [
        { model: model.Shop },
        { model: model.Product,
            include: [
                { model: model.File }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It can contain arrays of objects nested on multiple levels;
before sending it I can convert it to valid JSON if needed, like this:

```
var data =
{
    "include": [
        { "model": "model.Shop" },
        { "model": "model.Product",
            "include": [
                { "model": "model.File" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to send it as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: data
});
```

The problem is that when in the node server I do JSON.parse of the received string, the value of each property is a string and it is not recognized as a model object;

How can I make my server able to understand this?

Comment: *"I can convert it to valid JSON if needed, like this"* That's not JSON, that is still a JavaScript object. `{"foo": 42}` is the same as `{foo: 42}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I'm trying to send in headers "model.Shop" that is not defined in the Ember client (it's defined in the node server); so I think there's no way to do it; probably I should send a string and then write a function to parse it in the node server...

Comment: it's not working with `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Don't put manually quotes to your data object.

try

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

It will convert that to acceptable string format.